# How to execute a function for when a button is clicked in an array?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a very large array of 256 buttons laid out on a graph (for the example it will just be 5). I've already made a forEach statement with an event listener in it but it isn't doing what I want it to do. I want the button I click to turn black plain and simple, but I've tried setting up a console.log to test out my function and for each time I click one button it logs 256 times. I want the button to do an action for only the button I clicked in the array.

```js
let cells = document.querySelectorAll(".grid");

cells.forEach(() => {
    addEventListener("click", function(){
        target.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    margin:0;
}

#background {
    position:absolute;
    height:800px;
    width:800px;
    background-color:grey;
    top:100px;
    left:550px;
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(50px, 1fr));
}

.grid {
    display:block;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
}

.grid:hover {
    background-color:lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>FindMyKeys</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="background">
            <div id="grid1" class="grid"></div>
            <div id="grid2" class="grid"></div>
            <div id="grid3" class="grid"></div>
            <div id="grid4" class="grid"></div>
            <div id="grid5" class="grid"></div>
                </div>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your `forEach` a little:

```
cells.forEach((cell) => {
    cell.addEventListener("click", function(event){
        event.target.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    });
});
```

If your cells will always be inside an element, you can use event bubbling to your advantage:

```
document.getElementById("background").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    if (event.target.className == "grid") {
        event.target.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    }
});
```

Comment: Function arguments always confuse me damn

Comment: Yeah - so in the callback function of a `forEach` loop, the first parameter is the current item. Then you need to attach the listener to the item, and finally pass the `event` argument to the callback for `addEventListener` and use `event.target` (because just a plain `target` would result in an error as you wouldn't have defined `target` anywhere in your code).

Comment: Yes I tried to use target before and It gave me an error

Comment: Im trying to add opacity to the grid point and it isn't working could you help with that? `event.target.style.opacity = "75%";` doesn't work

Comment: so, 256 event listeners ? this is really bad ! only one is enough at all

Comment: Oh yes @MrJ - I forgot that. However, unlike jQuery, you can't add multiple listeners.

Comment: @TheNuthouse Try `event.target.style.opacity = 0.75;`

Comment: @Jack Bashford jquery is created in javascript, so tracking multiple events will always be multiple eventListener

Comment: Yes @MrJ - however you don't need to use jQuery just because it's built with JavaScript.

Comment: why talking about jQuery ?, my solution is pure javascript

Comment: @JackBashford Do you know a way for me to check where in the array the object I clicked on is im not very good at working with arrays

Comment: You can use jQuery's [`index`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) for that @TheNuthouse.

Comment: @JackBashford i don't use jQuery

Answer (score 2):

Why everyone ignore JS event delegation ?!!
(I have changing css values for snippet usage)

```js
document.querySelector("#background").onclick = function (e) {
  if (e.target.className !== 'grid') return;
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.target.style.backgroundColor = "black";
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#background {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: grey;
  top: 100px;
  left: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(50px, 1fr));
}
.grid {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
#background div {
  background-color: pink;
}
.grid:hover {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<div id="background">
  <div id="grid1" class="grid"></div>
  <div id="grid2" class="grid"></div>
  <div id="grid3" class="grid"></div>
  <div id="grid4" class="grid"></div>
  <div id="grid5" class="grid"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Im very interested in the answer but how does it work?

Comment: it's simple: any click on `#background` can happen first on any of the `.grid` elements